Can Ubuntu no longer be installed over newer Windows S laptops?
I was at the store to get a budget laptop to put Ubuntu on (Lenovo Ideapad 1i 15.6", Intel Core i3-1215U, 8GB memory).  The sales guy said that you can't install Ubuntu on that because of Windows S, and that even the Geek Squad couldn't override it, something about a bug.  I asked whether Ubuntu could be installed on Asus Windows S laptops (I have done that in the past just a couple of years ago, by booting from a thumb drive with the Ubuntu installer), but he said no, and that basically, all the newer Windows S laptops were that way.
Has anyone heard about this, and does anyone know of a way around it?

UPDATE: I went ahead and bought the laptop, disabled secure boot, and installed Ubuntu via flash drive installer as usual, and now it seems to be working fine!  So I guess it was just an incorrect rumor.

Do a bit more research on Windows S. As I understand it, you can only install apps from Windows store. Seem like a crippled system. Intel Core i3 should support any UEFI boot system, but do not know if Microsoft then makes vendors also cripple UEFI settings.

Thanks @oldfred, maybe to clarify, I'd plan to wipe Windows S off completely if it allows me to and replace it entirely with Ubuntu.  (I don't care about dual boot.)

This does sound like a classic case of a salesperson having no idea what product they’re actually selling. I don’t think S has anything to do with preventing you changing the os.

to me this is a windows question.... and we also do not support "hardware support"  question (that this also seems to be around)

Toggling out of S mode is trivial, just install the official S Mode Switch from Microsoft, so a laptop preloaded with Windows S doesn't imply anything special in the hardware. I assume those you asked simply don't want the hassle of supporting non-Windows since even Lenovo provides a tutorial to disable Secure Boot which only involves toggling the Secure Boot switch under Security tab in the UEFI.

Thanks, that's what I thought and had done it before, so I wasn't sure if something had changed.  I don't care about keeping S on there.

link only answers come with inherent difficulties. If the link is lost (or taken down) your answer looses its value. Please [edit] to include the basics of what needs to be done.
